# Add onclick event to SVG element

Tags: html, ajax, dom, svg

I found this example in a SVG tutorial that explains how you can use an `onclick` event handler for a SVG element. It looks like the code below:

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='600' width='820'>

  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
      function changerect(evt)
      {
        var svgobj=evt.target;
        svgstyle = svgobj.getStyle();
        svgstyle.setProperty ('opacity', 0.3);
        svgobj.setAttribute ('x', 300);
      }
    ]]>
  </script>

  <rect onclick='changerect(evt)' style='fill:blue;opacity:1' x='10' y='30' width='100'
        height='100' />
</svg>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens when I click on the element.

Perhaps it is important to mention the fact that I am displaying the SVG from inside a PHP script, using `echo`. Also, note that the content generated by the PHP script is brought into the page using AJAX and `XMLHttpRequest()`.

Could this perhaps have anything to do with it? Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your post doesn't seem to be asking a specific question.

Comment: The onclick event has no effect.. nothing happens when I click on the element. I have edited the question

Comment: Nothing happens (in 2020) because there is a `TypeError: svgobj.getStyle is not a function`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It appears that all of the JavaScript must be included inside of the SVG for it to run. I was unable to reference any external function, or libraries. This meant that your code was breaking at `svgstyle = svgobj.getStyle();`

This will do what you are attempting.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='600' width='820'>

  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
      function changerect(evt) {
        var svgobj=evt.target;
        svgobj.style.opacity= 0.3;
        svgobj.setAttribute ('x', 300);
      }
    ]]>
  </script>

  <rect onclick='changerect(evt)' style='fill:blue;opacity:1' x='10' y='30' width='100'height='100' />
</svg>
```

Comment: There are ways to reference external functions, works the same as calling external functions from inside an iframe. Some examples here: http://dahlström.net/svg/html/from-svg-to-parent-html-script.html and http://dahlström.net/svg/html/from-svg-get-embedding-element.html.

Answer (score 5):

[Demo in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/godly/zL5Su/1/)

```
    var _reg = 100;
    var _l = 10;

    // Create PATH element
    for (var x = 1; x < 20; x++) {
        var pathEl = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
        pathEl.setAttribute('d', 'M' + _l + ' 100 Q 100  300 ' + _l + ' 500');
        pathEl.style.stroke = 'rgb(' + (_reg) + ',0,0)';
        pathEl.style.strokeWidth = '5';
        pathEl.style.fill = 'none';
        $(pathEl).mousemove(function(evt) {
            $(this).css({ "strokeWidth": "3", "stroke": "#ff7200" })
                .hide(100).show(500).css({ "stroke": "#51c000" })
        });

        $('#mySvg').append(pathEl);
        _l += 50;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to click specific parts of the svg this might be a possible solution:

Put a div on top and add events to that div. z-index is not needed if the svg element is before the div tag in the html structure.

HTML

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='parent-events'></div>
  <div class='my-svg'><svg></svg></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.my-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.parent-events {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1
}
```

Javascript

```
const eventArea = document.querySelector('.parent-events');
eventArea.addEventListeners('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the svg node:

```
svgobj.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `className/id` to `<use>`; or to use the actual SVG path/element also, if you're detecting outside of SVG script scope:

```
<svg rel='-1' class='**ux-year-prev**' width="15px" height="15px" style="border:0px solid"><use class='**ux-year-prev**' xlink:href="#svg-arrow-left"></use></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this method of `onclick` event handler for a svg element:

```
var svgobj = parent_svg.find('svg')[0].children;

for (i = 0; i < svgobj.length; i++) {
   element = svgobj[i];
   element.style = "cursor: pointer;";
   $(element).click(function(evt){console.log($(this))});
}
```

Cek first whether your `svgobj`is passed to `console.log` when it is getting an `onclick` event handler. From that point you can pass to whatever functions to handle the element.

You may see on how it is working at a sample here:

https://jsfiddle.net/chetabahana/f7ejxhnk/20/

Note on how to use this sample:
- Change the status on the SVG Diagram to *Printed* option,
- Click one of the element then cek the output in your console.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the answer regarding the z-index placing it on top of the div helped!

However, I found that you do not need to wrap the svg in a div, you can just z-index it to the top instead as long as the parent is positioned.

Answer (score 0):

we can simply add an onclick event to svg

1. `<img class="video-svg" id="play" onclick="playVid(id)" src="assets/img/logo/play svg.png">`

then we can give css which will make the effect, for that we need to give position as absolute and z-index to 200 which will make the click event for svg

2.

```
.video-svg {
   margin: auto;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 7%;
   background: no-repeat;
   border: none;
   z-index: 200 !important;
   width: 10% !important;
   position: absolute !important;
}
```