# Dynamically adding onclick on SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg, onclick, dynamically-generated

I am creating some circles dynamically in svg and I want to add an `onlick` function to all of them. I know that it can be done like this: `<rect class="btn" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" onclick="alert('click!')" />`, but I am creting the elements like this:

```
            newCircle.setAttribute("class","circle");                                              
            newCircle.setAttribute("cx",centerX);                                                  
            newCircle.setAttribute("cy","850");                                                    
            newCircle.setAttribute("r","150");                                                     
            newCircle.style.stroke = "black";                                                      
            newCircle.style.strokeWidth = "2px";                                                   
            newCircle.style.opacity = circleOpacity[i-1];                                          
            newCircle.style.fill = circleColour[i];
            svgNode.appendChild(newCircle);
```

I tried adding this,

```
$(".circle").click(function() {
          onclick= "alert('click!')";

        })
```

but it doesnt work.

I also tried something like this:`newCircle.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction");`

How can I make it work? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472224/add-onclick-event-to-svg-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $(".circle").click(function() {
>      onclick= "alert('click!')";
> })
> ```

This should have been

```
$(".circle").click(function() {
    alert('click!');
})
```

> ```
> newCircle.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction");
> ```

This should have been

```
newCircle.setAttribute("onclick","myFunction()");
```

But, these days, the normal way to do this is as follows:

```
newCircle.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery('body').on('click','.circle',function(){
 alert('clicked')
})
```